# Creating an array of objects using an array of each object's name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I feel tantalizingly close here. Scenario: I have a JSON sent in a message that looks something like this:

```
{"objects": {
    "object_name1":{ 
        "name":"object_name1",
        "otherData":"some other data"
    },
    {"object_name2":{ 
        "name":"object_name2",
        "otherData":"some more data"
    }
}}
```

As you can see, the objects are not in an array. I created an array containing each Object's string name using the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function and then created *another* array which contains the objects that I want using an if statement, which leads to my current question:

How can I create an array of objects using the string values (the object keys) contained in the array I have created?

I've tried something like this:

```
filteredKeyArray = ['object_name1','object_name2'];
newObjArray = [];
for(i in filteredKeyArray){
    for(key in objects){
    newObjArray.push(objects[i[key]]);
    }
}
```

But the `newObjArray` is just displaying all undefined. Ideally the `newObjArray` displays something like this:

`[{"object_name1":{...}},{"object_name2":{...}}]`

Thoughts?

Comment: Your input's syntax is invalid, specifically the `}, {` part - objects have *key-value* pairs, not just plain values

Comment: That's not valid JSON - where did you get it?

Comment: What would you like your output to be? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including *desired output*.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand what you want to do correctly you want to create an iterable array containing the child objects of objectName?

I would do it as below, if you use the array prototype map function you can in one line of code iterate over all the keys of the object using Object.keys(target) and return the properties you want (in this case the inner child objects) as array elements via map.

```
strangeObject = {
    "objects":{
        "objectName_1":{
            "name":"x",
            "otherData":"some other data"
        },
        "objectName_2":{
            "name":"y",
            "otherData":"some other data"
        }
    }
}
const arrayOfObjects = Object.keys(strangeObject.objects).map(key => strangeObject.objects[key])
console.log(arrayOfObjects)
// logs [ { name: 'x', otherData: 'some other data' },
// { name: 'y', otherData: 'some other data' } ]
```

## mapped as in your example, method 1

```
const filteredKeyArray = ['x','y'];
const remappedArray = Object.keys(strangeObject.objects).map((key, i) => { 
    return { [filteredKeyArray[i]] : strangeObject.objects[key]}
})

console.log(remappedArray)
// logs [ { x: { name: 'x', otherData: 'some other data' } },
// { y: { name: 'y', otherData: 'some other data' } } ]
```

## iterating over the filteredKeyArray, method 2

```
const filteredIterator = filteredKeyArray.map((key, i) => {
    return { [key]: strangeObject.objects[Object.keys(strangeObject.objects)[i]]}
})

console.log(filteredIterator)
// logs [ { x: { name: 'x', otherData: 'some other data' } },
// { y: { name: 'y', otherData: 'some other data' } } ]
```

Note that these solutions assume that you will have a key in your filteredKeyArray to match the child object to as the map iterates through, you may want to add a check to check if the length of the filteredKeyArray is longer than the map iterator, or if filteredKeyArray[i] is undefined if using method 1. If using method two you may need to check for undefined before referencing Object.keys(strangeObject.objects)[i] as you may have less objects that fiteredKeyArray keys.

Comment: Thanks! Does it matter if the filteredKeyArray has more items within it than the nested objects in the initial remapping? Eg `filteredKeyArray = ['object_name1','object_name2']` and `{"strangeObject":{"object_name1":{...}}`

Comment: Personally I would map over the object and use the maps iterator to get you the relevant filteredKeyArray (as in method 1)  you could substitute that map return object key for [filteredKeyArray[i] || 'unnamed'] for example. That way if filteredKeyArray[i] is undefined youll get your default value (in this case unnamed) as the key instead of 'undefined. Happy hunting!